# Problem booting Kubuntu TPM_error, issue with Nvidia drivers? NVS 5400

Tags: 14.04, boot, drivers, nvidia, kubuntu

Regularly I have problem to boot a lenovo laptop "T530". It will say

```
 A TPM error (7) occured, attempting to read a PCR value.
```

Typically it will crash before the splash screen or freeze during splash screen.
Now, I have added this line

```
blacklist tpm_tis
```

in

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

But the problem still happens. Sometimes it will reboot correctly.
Sometimes it won't. I have the filling it is connected to nvidia driver. To sort things out I usualy go in safe mode than play around between "Nouveau" drivers and nividias binary until eventually, I can boot successfully in normal mode. Needless to say, it will last for a few days until the problem re-appears ...

## 1 ) How can a blacklisted module freeze a boot-up process ?

## 2 ) Any idea on how to sort it out ?

```
uname -a && lscpu && lspci |grep VGA &&lsmod |grep nvidia

Linux lenov 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 58
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               1199.960
CPU max MHz:           3300,0000
CPU min MHz:           1200,0000
BogoMIPS:              5187.84
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [NVS 5400M]

nvidia_uvm            745472  0
nvidia_drm             45056  1
nvidia_modeset        765952  6 nvidia_drm
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 nvidia_drm
drm                   364544  4 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
nvidia              11489280  154 nvidia_modeset,nvidia_uvm (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this sounds like that you have some element in your boot chain that tries to evaluate the system integrity during the boot process. PCRs hold SHA1-fingerprints of stuff executed during the boot process like the BIOS. When the code tries to read the PCR value, things go south.

Have a look into your BIOS/EFI. Go to the security tab. Here you should find settings related to "security chip" (which is the TPM).

I take the TPM is off. Try to enable it. Also try to enable the "security reporting" features of the TPM.

Reboot.